# Dynamic programming selecting tuples(size T) of nos with each not greater than k and sum S

Tags: c++, algorithm, dynamic-programming

Guys this is the question

In a tournament, N players play against each other exactly once. Each game results in either of the player winning. There are no ties. You have given a scorecard containing the scores of each player at the end of the tournament. The score of a player is the total number of games the player won in the tournament. However, the scores of some players might have been erased from the scorecard. How many possible scorecards are consistent with the input scorecard?

Input:
The first line contains the number of cases T. T cases follow. Each case contains the number N on the first line followed by N numbers on the second line. The ith number denotes s_i, the score of the ith player. If the score of the ith player has been erased, it is represented by -1.

Output:
Output T lines, containing the answer for each case. Output each result modulo 1000000007.

**I have reduced it to the above form of the question but it is failing on large inputs**.
This is starting to give me headaches.Any help will be appreciated. I have the following code..am i missing something any corner cases.

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    long long  solutionMatrix[781][41];
      long long
    noOfWays (int gamesUndecided, int inHowMany, int noOfPlayers)
    {
      if (inHowMany > 0 && gamesUndecided >= 0)
      {
        int i;
        long long result;
        for (i = noOfPlayers - 1, result = 0; i >= 0; i--)
        {
          if((gamesUndecided-i)>=0)
          {
            if (solutionMatrix[gamesUndecided - i][inHowMany - 1] == -1)
              solutionMatrix[gamesUndecided - i][inHowMany - 1] = noOfWays (gamesUndecided - i, inHowMany - 1, noOfPlayers);
            result += solutionMatrix[gamesUndecided - i][inHowMany - 1];
            result %=1000000007L;
          }
        }
        return result%1000000007L;
      }
      else
        return (inHowMany == 0 && gamesUndecided == 0) ? 1 : 0;
    }

      long long
    possibleCards (int score[], int noOfPlayers)
    {
      int i;
      int maxGames = (noOfPlayers * (noOfPlayers - 1)) / 2;
      int sumOfGames = 0, unDecided = 0;
      for (i = 0; i < noOfPlayers; i++)
      {
        if (score[i] != -1)
        {
          if (score[i] >= 0 && score[i] <= noOfPlayers - 1)
          {
            sumOfGames += score[i];
          }
          else
            return 0;
        }
        else
          unDecided++;
      }
      if (sumOfGames > maxGames || (unDecided==0 && sumOfGames < maxGames))
        return 0;
      if (sumOfGames==maxGames && unDecided==0)
        return 1;
      else
      {
        int j;
        for (i = 0; i < 781; i++)
          for (j = 0; j < 41; j++)
            solutionMatrix[i][j] = -1;
        return noOfWays (maxGames - sumOfGames, unDecided, noOfPlayers)%1000000007L;
      }
    }

      int
    main ()
    {
      int noOfTestCases;
      int score[41];
      printf("%u\n",0xffffffff);
      scanf ("%d", &noOfTestCases);
      for (; noOfTestCases > 0; noOfTestCases--)
      {
        int noOfPlayers;
        scanf ("%d", &noOfPlayers);
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < noOfPlayers; i++)
        {
          scanf ("%d", score + i);
        }
        printf ("%lld\n", possibleCards (score, noOfPlayers));
      }
      return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Its just a programming puzzle. I am stuck at it.Please guys help me out this is my first post.

Comment: I have done the same thing also but mine is failing for other test cases.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How many possible scorecards are consistent with the input scorecard?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11284978/how-many-possible-scorecards-are-consistent-with-the-input-scorecard)

Comment: @bali I have edited my original answer. Please have a look. http://stackoverflow.com/a/12541135/1088243

Comment: What's the programming competition this task is from? It should still be active if two people ask the same question in less than a day.